# Android: problem creating user form from a menu

Tags: android

I'm very new to programming in Android, but have been struggling all day with a problem and would appreciate your help.

I'm trying to create a form to get user information (essentially a new contact) which is accessed from the menu.  When I click the button to create the new form, I get the following error:

> "Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@626fd5e0"

This is my code:
The menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/settings_search"
        android:alphabeticShortcut="@string/settings_shortcut_search" />
    <item android:id="@+id/new_contact"
        android:title="@string/settings_new"
        android:alphabeticShortcut="@string/settings_shortcut_new" />
</menu>
```

The code for calling the new activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_contact:
        //activities to create a new account
        //startActivity(new Intent(this, Prefs.class));


            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewContact.class);
            startActivity(i);
            //addSaver("String");
            return true;
        case R.id.search:

            return true;
    // More items go here (if any) ...
    }
    return false;
}
```

The view for the new contact activity:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">"
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a test\nsecond line\n"/>
       <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_contact_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/submit" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And the code for the new activity:

```
public class NewContact extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_contact);

        // Set up click listeners for all the buttons
        View newContactButton = findViewById(R.id.new_contact_button);
        newContactButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Bizarrely if I comment out the button from the class and from the xml then it works correctly and opens up the new activity (but of course I can't do anything with that activity).

Comment: Do you have inside your layout new_contact.xml the button new_contact_button? post your new_contact.xml

Comment: Thanks @dave.c for making the xml show... how did you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your button xml code, you are missing

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

add that and give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks, now the button is working.  I'm having the exact same problem with the EditText field, am I missing something similar there: \n       <EditText android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="@string/compose_name"></EditText>

Comment: I'm not seeing it.  When I have this sort of problem I try adding things back in one piece at a time.  Try making the simplest version that works, then adding your additional attributes one at a time.